# How do I remove a template that I inserted in meteor?

Tags: meteor

The problem that I'm having is that I'm inserting the login bar and the registration bar using two templates call "login" and "register". What I would like to do is when a user log in. The register template should be removed. I'm not able to find a good solution to remove a template programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

handlebars has helper like {{currentUser}}

```
{{#unless currentUser}}
    show signin / signup view
{{/unless}}

{{#if currentUser}}
    show if user is loggedin
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I need to go back and read the full handlebars docs. I have only read some basic tutorial on it and it seem that it doesn't cover it.

Comment: see meteor wiki page, https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Handlebars and auth wiki https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Auth, to use edge version of meteor use https://github.com/possibilities/meteorite, easy and handy

Comment: @JonathanShepherd these helpers, `currentUser` and `currentUserLoaded`, won't be in the Handlebars docs. They're global Handlebars helpers registered from Meteor's `accounts-base` package, and they're current [not documented](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/446).